# SSRS Highlight Cell/Row on Mousemove/Hover Event

Tags: javascript, css, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I'm trying to achieve something like [Fancy HTML/CSS Table](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_fancy) in SSRS tablix.

So far, I've tried using `div` tag with `style` property to set `hover color` using the following data value (I've altered my `SQL` to get the following string as a column value):

```
Column1 = <div style="hover {background-color: yellow;}"><span><a> MY DATA </a></span></div>
```

and then by simply using

```
=Fields!Column1.Value
```

and selecting `HTML-Interpret HTML tags...`  property for `placeholder` but no luck.

Another option that I think can work is to use `Javascript` like we use for `Action` property but I can't figure out how to use that?

The limitation I've is that I can't play with `Reporting Server` level `Stylesheet` but I need an embedded solution at the report level. Can somebody help me with that, please? 
Thanks in advance  :)